# How to bundle pairs of trips?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, constraints

I have a database of real-time trip demands:

```
ID,EndDateEnd,EndDateStart,StartDateEnd,StartDateStart,DepX,DepY,ArrX,ArrY
1,2021-03-04,2021-03-03,2021-03-02,2021-03-01,2.83689,47.3324,-0.5854,44.83814
2,2021-03-04,2021-03-03,2021-03-02,2021-03-01,2.44774,47.56044,0.13888,49.49015
3,2021-03-10,2021-03-09,2021-03-08,2021-03-07,2.76755,47.97472,0.65567,48.78064
...
```

It is a list of load offers that companies need delivered at a certain location and time.

My goal is to bundle pairs of loads that increase my truck's paid miles. I normally have a set destination and origin. Let's say I'm going from NYC to CHICAGO. Then I search on the trip database for loads that need to be delivered along that route. Imagine I find one with a pickup in Pittsburg and delivery in Cleveland. Then my paid miles would be the driving distance from Pittsburg to Cleveland. But I'm not getting paid for getting from NYC to Pittsburg or from Cleveland to Chicago. A picture is better.

[image: Picture]

In blue you can see the paid miles and red the not paid miles. If I could find another trip from NYC to Pittsburgh it would be great or Cleveland-Chicago as well.

Now the question is how can I algorithmically find pairs of loads that **go well together**?

One solution:

You could define that two loads "go well together" if the miles driven from only one truck doing both loads is lower than two trucks doing each one of the loads.

That is the intuition behind the Clark and Wright Savings Method.

$$ Savings = d(Start, Pickup_1) + d(End, Delivery_2 ) - d(Delivery_1, Pickup_2) $$

Being d your favourite distance function. In our example, start is NYC and END is Chicago.

This is a type of vehicle routing problem that is sometimes called pick up and delivery with time windows(PDPTW)
I'm trying to solve a smaller part of them problem. Just finding useful pairs of trips.

Are there any other solutions out there? Scaleable approaches to bundling?

Relevant Research Papers:

- [Pick up and delivery problems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221709002999)
- [Freight market](https://api.research-repository.uwa.edu.au/ws/portalfiles/portal/33899497/THESIS_DOCTOR_OF_PHILOSOPHY_BRAUN_Hendrik_2018.pdf)

Comment: It may come as a surprise to you that most people responding in this forum actually know very little about the trucking industry, and therefore do not know all the various details that apparently seem obvious to you, but are necessary to make sense of your problem. We are mathematicians, and before we can help you with this problem, you need to convert it into a mathematical problem. First of all that means defining all the terms. What does it mean for a pair of loads to "go well together"? Even when you attempt to bring in math, you leave it undefined. What is "$d$"?

Comment: Hey @PaulSinclair I added more information to the post. Hopefully it clarifies the questions.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8159/how-to-bundle-pairs-of-trips